# Java display file line by line using Enter key

Tags: java, readfile

I'm trying to progress displaying a file line by line with an Enter key, but the if statement that I try doesn't seem to work. If I disregard the if statement, it works, but it feels incomplete because then I'm asking for input and doing nothing with it.

This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class LineByLine  {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the filename?");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    String sen = buff.readLine();
    System.out.println(sen);
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sen != null){
            String output = enter.next();
            if (output.equals("")){
                System.out.println(sen = buff.readLine());
            }
    }
   }
}
```

I just don't know why my if statement doesn't work.

Comment: Change `String output = enter.next();` to `String output = enter.nextLine();`

Comment: I'd also change the if statement to `if (output.trim().isEmpty()){`

Comment: By god that worked! I swear I tried that before and it didn't and I read you could use next() or nextLine(). I feel dumb now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that you misunderstand Scanner and its default configuration: Out of the box, scanner splits on *any amount* of whitespace. `.next()` asks for the next token; a token is the thing that appears in between the whitespace.

Thus, pressing enter 500 times produces **zero** tokens. After all, tokens are what's in between the separator, and the default separator is 'any amount of whitespace'. Pressing enter a bunch of time is still just you entering the same separator.

The underlying problem is that most people appear to assume that Scanner reads one line at a time. It doesn't do that. At all. But you want it to. So, tell it to! Easy peasy - make scanner do what you already thought it did:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\\R"); // a single enter press is now the separator.
```

You should also stop using `nextLine` on scanners. `nextLine` and any other `next` call do not mix. The easiest way to solve this problem is to only ever use `nextLine` and nothing else, *or*, never use `nextLine`. With the above setup, `.next()` gets you a token **which is an entire line** - thus, no need for nextLine, which is good news, as nextLine is broken (it does what the spec says it should, but what it does is counterintuitive. We can debate semantics on whether 'broken' is a fair description of it. Point is, it doesn't do what you think it does).

Also, while you're at it, don't make multiple scanners. And, to improve this code, resources must be properly closed. You're not doing that. Let's use try-with, that's what it is for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  in.useDelimiter("\\R");
  System.out.println("What is the filename?");
  String input = in.next();
  try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input))) {
    String sen = buff.readLine();
    System.out.println(sen);
    while (sen != null){
      enter.next(); // why does it matter _what_ they entered?
      // as long as they pressed it, we're good, right? Just ignore what it returns.
      System.out.println(sen = buff.readLine());
    }
  }
}
```